# Sanitizers VS dangerouslySetInnerHtml

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xss, gatsby, sanitization

According to some [React documentation](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html):

> Improper use of the `innerHTML` can open you up to a cross-site
> scripting (XSS) attack. Sanitizing user input for display is
> notoriously error-prone, and failure to properly sanitize is one of
> the leading causes of web vulnerabilities on the internet.

It seems that improper usage of the sanitizers and the `innerHTML` can expose the site XSS (Cross-Site Scripting) attacks.

On the other hand, according to other documentation (such as [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/security-in-gatsby/#how-can-you-prevent-cross-site-scripting) or [sanitizers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) itself), they are recommended:

> The most straightforward way to prevent a XSS attack is to sanitize
> the innerHTML string before dangerously setting it. Fortunately, there
> are npm packages that can accomplish this; packages like [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html)
> and [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify).

What's the best and safest approach to avoid exposing an application to XSS attacks in React while also avoiding improper usage of sanitizers?

Comment: using DOMPurify to sanitize the string and then using dangerouslySet to actually assign it to the element.

Comment: The safest approach clearly is to not use `innerHTML`. You shouldn't need it unless you provide possibility for a user to enter actual markup that you want to display in your app. A rich text editor functionality would be an example for that. If you really need to render user provided markup you need to make sure to use the best sanitizer available. Which one is best is opinion-based. Also having the proper [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP#:~:text=Content%20Security%20Policy%20(CSP)%20is,defacement%20to%20distribution%20of%20malware.) is important

Comment: So, how to proceed in case you want to render a markdown coming from a CMS without using an `innerHtml`?

Comment: @FerranBuireu Formatted rich text in any kind of markup (markdown, html, etc.) is a valid use case. In this case you should use a good sanitizer for markdown.

Comment: @FerranBuireu You don't need to subvert React's sanitization of `children` in order to use Markdown. There are a number of libraries, like [markdown-to-jsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx), that convert Markdown to JSX (and not to arbitrary strings of HTML that you have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` on).

Comment: That's an interesting point @coreyward , thanks for answering. Maybe it's the safest and the most native approach to avoid using a sanitize library while using a parsing library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best, safest, and optimal approach, as it has been said through comments (especially by [Corey Ward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203130/coreyward)) is to avoid the usage of the `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` as long as it is possible prior to sanitizers. There are some amazing libraries such as [markdown-to-jsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx) that extends the benefits of `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` (rendering HTML) without exposing the web to XSS attacks.

If the only solution for the use-case is to use`dangerouslySetInnerHtml`, then the solution **must** be using sanitizers, keeping in mind that it should be configured to keep styles, classes, and other desired behavior to avoid losing changes.

Answer (score 1):

The two options are not in contrast with each other:

> **Improper use** of the innerHTML can open you up to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack

Emphasis on 'improper'.

> **sanitize** the innerHTML string before dangerously setting it

Using an established and well-known library to sanitize the input before setting it is safe, because it is not an improper use of innerHTML.

Comment: It's *relatively* safe, not inherently safe. The sanitizer library can have an incomplete implementation and has to be properly maintained. Also the sanitizer library can be compromised itself. It's unlikely but it can happen and it did happen.

Comment: That applies to everything though, even openssl and similar software. It is definitely better than sanitizing the input yourself unless you put months of development into the feature

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would like to know more in details what's known as "improper" use of sanitizing and how to handle the typical usage of it in a React application

Comment: Rolling out your own sanitize function, that probably misses a ton of edge cases. A naive solution would be to remove every `<script>` tag, and an attacker inserting `<scr<script>ipt>` woud bypass your solution