# Embed <script> tag into React Gatsby Component

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to embed the podcast player provided by Buzzsprout. This is the code they provide.

```
<div id="buzzsprout-player-61XX09"></div>
<script src="https://www.buzzsprout.com/14XX79/61XX09-the-podcast-promo.js?container_id=buzzsprout-player-61XX09&player=small" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The intention is to have multiple players on a single page, a list of podcast episodes. However the above code does not work with a Gatsby component. I've search for ways to include this and unable to find a solution.

I have tried the following but this does not work.

```
const IndexPage = () => (
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `src="https://www.buzzsprout.com/14XX79/61XX09-the-podcast-promo.js?container_id=buzzsprout-player-61XX09&player=small" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"`}} />
)
```

Spent a while trying other options such as the `react-script-tag` package but uses deprecated methods and does not work. Any help would be great!

Comment: Try adding the <script> tag using react-helmet on ejecting the html.js page on gatsby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<Helmet>` component:

```
const IndexPage = () => (
<>
  <Helmet>
    <script defer src="https://www.buzzsprout.com/14XX79/61XX09-the-podcast-promo.js?container_id=buzzsprout-player-61XX09&player=small" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" />
  </Helmet>
</>
)
```

Basically, the `<Helmet>` (imported from `react-helmet`) component puts inside the `head` tag everything that has wrapped inside. You may want to play with the `defer` attribute if needed (thanks [@LekoArts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10164092/lekoarts) for the reference at https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/30752).

Keep in mind that with your approach, you are [exposing the site to XSS (**C**ross-**S**ite **S**cripting) attacks](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/security-in-gatsby/) since you are using [`dangerouslySetInnerHtml`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) (hence the name). You can use some [parse libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261021/sanitizers-vs-dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to avoid its usage if needed. Using `<Helmet>` approach your site is completely safe.

---

The issue has been solved using a native `iframe` for this use-case.

Comment: This works in dev, but once built the page is broken. The player appears at the top of the page a the start of the `<body>` element. I'm sure it's something to do with the react lifecycle but can't be sure what exactly. Any ideas on why?

Comment: Are you trying to print your script inside a certain div? That's a game-changer.

Comment: Yes pretty much. The player looks for a `<div>` with a specific `id` to inject the iframe into.

Comment: What about using a native `iframe`? Will it work for your use-case?

Comment: Great mind ha, just tried it and yes it works! The embed code has different `id`'s and the injected `iframe` is inclusive of podcast title. Adding `iframe` manually means updating `id` and manually changing the `title` attribute. Which is not so bad. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You'll want to add the `defer` tag to the script, see: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/30752